# How to install latest version of Urban Terror on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, games, urban-terror

I am new to Ubuntu. Please tell me how to install the latest version of Urban Terror. Step by step answer would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard solution is to add [getdeb](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/12.04#how_to_install) games [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and install the games from there. The problem is that the original getdeb repositories are bit unreliable as they often go down. Therefore better option is to add getdeb repository mirror that has all the same stuff and is more reliable. The downside is that updates come with slight delay but I would not worry about that.

Easy way to add repository is by opening Software center and Edit-> Software sources -> Other software -> Add (or something like that :)
In the case of getdeb mirror enter this line (you can remove "apps" if you don't want to get also software from there):

```
deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps games
```

If you are also interested in the source code then you can also add this the same way:

```
deb-src http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps games
```

If after adding repositories close Software center, open Terminal and enter (you can copy this - in terminal copy/paste can only be done with mouse) this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

At this point you would also need to enter your password.
If that doesn't produce any errors (as it shouldn't) you just managed add new software sources to your Ubuntu.

You can now install Urban Terror by opening Software center and searching for it.
Alternative is to continue in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install urbanterror
```

After some waiting you can start shooting.

---

UPDATE: If somebody is reading this to learn how to install the game on any other version than 12.04 (Precise) then replace the "precise" in the repository line with your version of Ubuntu. 
For example: `deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps games`

The same thing from command line:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

The original answer also did not include information about adding the repository key. This can be done from command line with:

```
$ wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Or one could download [the repository key file](http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key) and import it at the "Authentication" tab of "Software and updates" window.

Comment: I think it is not there on Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @vishalmishra. It is not under Games but it is there. After you have made sure that you followed all the given steps open Software center and enter "urban terror", "urban" or "urbanterror" to the search field. I have the same setup and it does show up. What you need to install is called "Urban Terror client binary" with package name "urbanterror" below it. But if for some reason unknown to me the game is still not there just use the terminal command to install it.

Comment: Great answer, just does not work in 13.10 - note the `precise-getdeb` in the repository link. :-(

Answer (score 5):

Download the [Game installer/updater for Linux](http://www.urbanterror.info/downloads/). I assume you downloaded the file [`UrbanTerror42.tar.gz`](http://www.urbanterror.info/downloads/software/urt/42/UrbanTerror42.tar.gz) and saved it in the Downloads folder.

1. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and change into Downloads folder: `cd Downloads/`
2. Extract the archive: `tar -xvf UrbanTerror42.tar.gz`
3. Change into UrbanTerror directory: `cd UrbanTerror42/`
4. Start the UrTUpdater GUI:

   - for 32 bit systems: `./UrTUpdater.i386`
   - for 64 bit systems: `./UrTUpdater.x86_64`
5. Accept the license agreement.

   [image: license agreement]
6. Click the Download button to download the neccessary files.

   [image: download files]
7. Wait.

   [image: wait / downloading]
8. Play.

   [image: click play button]

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 13.10, this works:

Add the key and the Ubuntu Games repository:

```
 wget -q -O - 'http://archive.ubuntugames.org/ubuntugames.key' | sudo apt-key add -
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntugames.org ubuntugames main"
 sudo apt-get update
```

And then, you can install it *(though it is rather large - 1666 Megabytes)*:

```
 sudo apt-get install urban-terror
```

If it does not work (can't find `libSDL-1.2.so.0` error), install this:

```
 sudo apt-get install libsdl*
```

Then run the Updater, and it'll work :-)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste friendly / Ubuntu version agnostic version of what [Tanel said](https://askubuntu.com/a/290224/52975):

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu '"$(lsb_release -cs)"'-getdeb apps games" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install urbanterror
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the UrbanTerror42.tar.gz (http://www.urbanterror.info/downloads/software/urt/42/UrbanTerror42.tar.gz)

Extract it to your desktop

Open the folder

Run: UrTUpdater.i386 if you have 32bit
     UrTUpdater.x86_64 if you have 64bit

IT WORKS FINE FOR UBUNTU 14.04