# .zip file not getting extracted

Tags: command-line, software-installation, archive, urban-terror

I have downloaded linux game Urban Terror using flareget download manager which is 1.7 GB. The download seems to be completed without errors but it is not getting opened with archive manager and I get the below output from terminal.

```
 rehanullahafridi@rehanullahafridi:~$ unzip UrbanTerror42_full023.zip
Archive:  UrbanTerror42_full023.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of UrbanTerror42_full023.zip or
        UrbanTerror42_full023.zip.zip, and cannot find UrbanTerror42_full023.zip.ZIP, period.
```

- Will I have to redownload the file or any solution is present. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Wfich version of flareget did you use? If you used the one available in Ubuntu Software Center (which is years old - not recommended) than file may be corrupted.

Comment: It you want to install the latest version of UrbanTerror, [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/290006/178596) question may help.

Comment: @adnankamili The version of flareget is 4.1.80(stable)

Comment: @Wilf will the downloader resume the download in case of power loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For big downloads you should use checksums to verify, flarget has support for checksums, but since you have already downloaded the file you can verify checksum from commnad line:

> openssl md5 name-of-file

and compare it with one on their server. Usually their server puts restriction on multi-segmented downloads and interupts resuming also, multi segmented download is not a good option. The warning displayed is:

> WARNING
>
> You are limited to 3 concurrent downloads, with a total bandwith of
>   1.4 MB/s.
>
> You are using 1 download slots at 1.4 MB/s max.
>
> If you stop a download before it has completed, the slot will stay
>   blocked for 1 min .

So the chances than a multi-segment download will corrupt the file is high as server wants to restrict you from doing so.

Now, open the terminal in the download folder and execute following command:

> openssl md5 UrbanTerror42_full023.zip

It will take some time as file is big. The output will be a string. If the output matches:

> 20b4e2d10d9e1e76a6b050f1df3a3669

Than your file was downloaded without any corruption, if not than file is corrupted. You need to download the file again. If you want to use flareget again make sure you only use one segment for download.

Comment: As far I know this is a single file 1.7 GB. No parts are available on the site. Thanks for support.

Comment: @RehanUllah For big downloads you should use checksums to verify, flarget has support for checksums, but since you have already downloaded the file you can verify checksum from commnad line

Comment: On the website the checksum is "20b4e2d10d9e1e76a6b050f1df3a3669" While the checksums according to the terminal of the file I have downloaded is "24105f1f83797bef30a552698939a08b". They really do not match at all. Thanks for your precious help.